# why is showing only first row of mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, echo

I have a pagination that have over 30 records and works great under table name "product". I also created another table name "Note" under same database, that note is allow me to read note of each product.

And now I'm trying to add new column features in pagination to check to see if any records already exist in "note" table using product_id number.

```
<?php 
$sql = new mysqli($mysql_hostname, $mysql_user, $mysql_password, 
$mysql_database);
$query = "SELECT product_id FROM notes WHERE product_id = $product_id";
$result = mysqli_query($sql, $query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    if(isset($row['$product_id'])) {
    echo "<p>No note </p>";
    } else {
    echo "<p>have note </p>";
    } 
?>
```

The problem I have is that in "note" table has 3 records, and when I run pagination, is showing only first row that are not exit any note... and is only one records instead of All records (30 records).. I did NOT put "limit 1 ) in WHERE statements ...

My question is that how can I write php code to allow me ALL records whether has note or not but show in each records column "no note" or "have note" if "product_id" number exit or not!

many thanks for help.

Comment: Are all three records in the Note table for the product in question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mysqli_fetch_array` returns an array per row, and requires you to loop the call to work with each result.  Also, to call an element from the array you need `$row['product_id']` not `$row['$product_id']`

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){

     if(isset($row['product_id'])) {
         echo "<p>No note </p>";
     } else {
         echo "<p>have note </p>";
     } 
}
```

If you want to display all records from the database, regardless of `product_id`, you can change your query to:

```
$query = "SELECT product_id FROM notes";
```

Comment: I have tried from lasAnders and still not working, still getting one result instead of all. what i like to show all no matter if is exist or not.

Comment: Are you sure that there are three records where the `product_id` field is equal to the `$product_id` you are searching on?

Comment: If you want to show all whether there is a match or not, then you can change your SQL query to: `$query = "SELECT product_id FROM notes";`

Answer (score 2):

You need to loop through the result.

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    // do something
}
```

Checking `isset($row['product_id'])` is pointless - if it doesn't equal `$product_id` then that row won't be returned by the query anyway.

Answer (score -1):

You need to iterate through `mysqli_fetch_array`. Try this instead

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
          if(isset($row['$product_id'])) {
                  echo "<p>No note </p>";
          } else {
                  echo "<p>have note </p>";
          } 
}
```

Comment: I have tried any above code, and I'm still showing one record of first row, that is not working, What i need is to show all records instead of one record... any other idea!